# Implementation of an ArrayWritable for a custom Hadoop type

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How do I define an ArrayWritable for a custom Hadoop type ? I am trying to implement an inverted index in Hadoop, with custom Hadoop types to store the data

I have an *Individual Posting* class which stores the term frequency, document id and list of byte offsets for the term in the document.

I have a *Posting* class which has a document frequency (number of documents the term appears in) and list of Individual Postings

I have defined a LongArrayWritable extending the ArrayWritable class for the list of byte offsets in *IndividualPostings*

When i defined a custom ArrayWritable for *IndividualPosting* I encountered some problems after local deployment (using Karmasphere, Eclipse).

All the *IndividualPosting* instances in the list in Posting class would be the same, even though I get different values in the Reduce method

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the problem was?  Maybe post some code for your custom ArrayWritable?

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation of [`ArrayWritable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html):

> A Writable for arrays containing instances of a class. The elements of this writable must all be instances of the same class. If this writable will be the input for a Reducer, you will need to create a subclass that sets the value to be of the proper type. For example:  `public class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable { public IntArrayWritable() { super(IntWritable.class); } }`

You've already cited doing this with a [`WritableComparable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html) type defined by Hadoop. Here's what I assume your implementation looks like for [`LongWritable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/LongWritable.html):

```
public static class LongArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable
{
    public LongArrayWritable() {
        super(LongWritable.class);
    }
    public LongArrayWritable(LongWritable[] values) {
        super(LongWritable.class, values);
    }
}
```

You should be able to do this with any type that implements [`WritableComparable`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html), as given by [the documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html). Using their example:

```
public class MyWritableComparable implements
        WritableComparable<MyWritableComparable> {

    // Some data
    private int counter;
    private long timestamp;

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(counter);
        out.writeLong(timestamp);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        counter = in.readInt();
        timestamp = in.readLong();
    }

    public int compareTo(MyWritableComparable other) {
        int thisValue = this.counter;
        int thatValue = other.counter;
        return (thisValue < thatValue ? -1 : (thisValue == thatValue ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

And that should be that. This assumes you're using revision `0.20.2` or `0.21.0` of the Hadoop API.