# Emit a List From Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to emit a List from Mapper.

```
List<String> mapFinalList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is there any way to emit a List  or should I create a `Custom Writable` for my List.

Please Suggest.

**UPDATE**

I tried it using ArrayWritable

```
public static class ListWritable extends ArrayWritable
{
  public ListWritable() {
  super(Text.class);
  }
}
ListWritable passList = new ListWritable();
ArrayWritable[] data = new ArrayWritable[dummy.size()];
for (int k = 0; k < dummy.size(); k++) {
   data[k] = new ArrayWritable(dummy.toArray(new String[dummy.size()]));
}
passList.set(data);
context.write(new Text(""), passList);
```

But showing the output as

```
pck.Driver$ListWritable@75e287e5
```

Am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the whole list in memory and emitting it in one shot could be dangerous and non-scalable. Unless you have a strong requirement to emit a whole list of `string` in one shot, I would rather implement a loop in the mapper, and emit each `String` individually.

Answer (score 3):

You may use already implemented [ArrayWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html) for this purposes. Or look at [other classes](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) implementing Writable interface.

Comment: You can easily transform your list to Array, using the `List.toArray(T[])` method, where the parameter will be initialized as an Array of size `mapFinalList.size()`. Then , you can create an ArrayWritable with this array as a parameter

Comment: String [] dummyarray = dummy.toArray(new String[dummy.size()]);
context.write(new Text(""), new ArrayWritable(dummyarray));
But showing java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.<init>()

Comment: Please, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386781/implementation-of-an-arraywritable-for-a-custom-hadoop-type/4390928#4390928) answer. 

If this writable will be the input for a Reducer, you will need to create a subclass that sets the value to be of the proper type. For example: public class StringArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable { public StringArrayWritable() { super(Text.class); } }

Comment: Given your initial line of code you only need this:

 `new ArrayWritable(mapFinalList.toArray(new String[mapFinalList.size()]));`

Comment: ys did. but how to display the actual value?

Comment: If my answer solved your original problem, please accept it as a solution. As I see you have many new questions now which may lead to an endless thread ;))